# Finding QGridLayout elements in Qt

Tags: qt

I created labels and added them to the layout. How to get the elements from the layout? I tried to use method children(), but it gives empty list... Is there a way to get them? Some sample code below.

```
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
QLabel* test = new QLabel();
test->setPixmap(m_staticStorage->getFirstImg());
test->setScaledContents(true);

QLabel* test2 = new QLabel();
test2->setMaximumSize(50,50);
test2->setPixmap(m_staticStorage->getSecondImg());
tes2->setScaledContents(true);

layout->addWidget(worker, 0, 0);
layout->addWidget(farmer, 0, 1);
ui->verticalLayout->addLayout(layout);
//layout->children() ->>>> empty
```

Comment: Maybe using `QLayout::itemAt()` is a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will iterate over any `QLayout` subclass to find the items which have been added so far:

```cpp
  for (int i=0; i < layout->count(); ++i) {
    QLayoutItem *item = layout->itemAt(i);
    if (!item || !item->widget())
      continue;
    QLabel *label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(item->widget());
    if (label) {
      // .... do stuff with label
    }
  }
```

One can also iterate in a similar fashion over each row or column of a `QGridLayout` using `QGridLayout::columnCount()` or `QGridLayout::rowCount()` and then `QGridLayout::itemAtPosition()` to get the actual QLayoutItem.

If you need to uniquely identify the QLabel after finding it, you could for example give each label a unique `objectName` or do a `setProperty()` on them with a unique ID when creating them.

```
QLabel *test1 = new QLabel(this);
test1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("test1"));

....
     if (label) {
       if (!label->objectName().compare(QLatin1String("test1")))
          // this is "test1" label
     }
```

```
QLabel *test1 = new QLabel(this);
test1->setProperty("id", 1);

....
     if (label) {
       if (label->property("id").toInt() == 1)
          // this is "test1" label
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the function [QObject::findChild](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild)

Qt is returning all children of a given Type and Objectname. You can decide to get only direct children or also all recursively.

```
this->findChild<QLabel*>(QString(), Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly);
```

This will return all **direct children** of `this` (where this is your parent widget, not your layout) with **any name** and of type **QLabel***

Your approach do not work because the layout do not take the ownership of the labels:

From [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html):

> **Tips for Using Layouts**
>
> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. *The layout will automatically
>   reparent the widgets* (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are
>   children of the widget on which the layout is installed.
>
> **Note: Widgets in a layout are children of the widget on which the**
>   **layout is installed, not of the layout itself. Widgets can only have**
>   **other widgets as parent, not layouts.**
>
> You can nest layouts using addLayout() on a layout; the inner layout
>   then becomes a child of the layout it is inserted into.

BTW: Don't forget to set a parent for your layout

```
QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(this);
```

and for your labels too

```
QLabel* test2 = new QLabel(this);
```

Comment: You only set parent of the top-level layout on a QWidget, not on any sub-layouts which get added to that top-level one. Only one top-level layout is allowed per widget, and Qt will show a warning message if you try to assign another one (even if "just" naming a parent for the sub-layout). The OPs example shows the grid layout is not the top-level one. Parenting the QLabels is a good idea though.

Comment: Also instead of "this->findChild()... This will return all direct children of layout" it would more accurate to say that it would return children of type QLabel of `this` QObject, in _any_ layout (or in no layout), not in any specific layout.